# Detect click in iframe (React.js)

Tags: html, reactjs, iframe

I have an iframe, and I want to prevent people from downloading the contents. I have already used #toolbar=0, but a user can still right-click to download. I know it's impossible to completely prevent downloads, but I'm just looking for a solution to prevent easy downloads for the basic user.

I have tried overlaying the iframe with a transparent image to block the right-click, but that makes it impossible to scroll through the document.

**The goal right now**: detect a right-click ***in the iframe***, and disable the context menu.

The code that I have right now is:

```
componentDidMount(){
 document.getElementById('myIframe').addEventListener("click",this.handleClick);
}
componentWillUnmount(){
 document.getElementById("myIframe").removeEventListener("click", this.handleClick);
}

render(){
  return(
     <div className="PDFs">
       <iframe id="myIframe" src={PDF + "#toolbar=0"} width="100%" height="800px" className="Viewer"/> 
     </div>
  );
}
```

But it only works if your mouse is on the exact line of pixels that outlines the iframe. Not very useful.

**If you can find any way to prevent the downloading of a PDF without converting the PDF to anything and without blocking scrolling access to the PDF, I'll take it.**

Some more info: the page that this will be displayed on will only show this viewer and nothing else. If I can disable the context menu for this entire page, that would be brilliant.

I have also already tried using "onClickDown" and "onContextMenu" and neither of them worked, unless I was using it wrong.

Comment: What you're asking for is fundamentally impossible. Even if you did disable the context menu, a user could still open up the devtools, inspect the network requests and download the data that way. As long as your data goes from some server onto the user's browser, at that point it's as good as "their data" - and they can do whatever they want with it (with possible legal consequences, of course).

Comment: That's totally fine. I just want to prevent basic users from having a straight up download button a couple of clicks away. If you have a way to do that, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: I looked in the CSP-Settings but you also cant do it with these. The Iframe simulates another website so you can't just alter it's content. Why do you need an iframe from this site and is it ok for me to ask the link for the iframe source?

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I only need an iframe to display the pdf. If you know a way of displaying a pdf that's much more editable, that would be great. The iframe source will just be displaying a pdf, so any pdf will do in its place. If you need a placeholder pdf, then I can send you my math homework hahaha.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe iframe sandbox is the way to go.

Answer (score -2):

```
document.getElementById('myIframe').contentDocument.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```

Comment: this didn't work :(. I can still select text in the pdf AND right click to download.

Comment: Did it work for you? And if so, can you show me what you did in entirety?